# Spoofing phone calls to test call center queuing logic

Tags: asterisk

I have an asterisk pbx that I'm setting up for a call center. Basically callers go to a queue and when call agents can answer they are removed from the queue. I need to test to see how it will behave with high call volume. I would like to spoof 100 calls to see if the system behaves as its suppose to. Is there a software tool to help with this testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SIPp

http://sipp.sourceforge.net/

This is standard tool for SIP performance tests. From beginning it is not so easy to use, but it have very flexible and you can write your own scripts for it. It will work if you just need to set-up 100 call and it will work well even if you want to set-up 100000 calls. It is widely used and there is dozens examples online.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this solution.